# Installing error Datastax-PHP driver on windows

Tags: php, windows, cassandra, datastax

I'm trying to run the vc_build.bat file. 
But I always get the following:

```
Build Type:          DEBUG
Clean Build:         1
Target Architecture: 64
Test Configuration:  0
Visual Studio:       2015
C/C++ Driver
Use Boost Atomic:  0
PHP Executable
PHP Version:       php-5.6.22
ZTS:               1

Cleaning build directory ... done.

Cloning Library Dependencies
Update cpp-driver submodule ... done.
Cloning MPIR 2.7.2 ... done.
Cloning PHP php-5.6.22 ... done.

Building Library Dependencies
The system cannot find the path specified.
Building and installing cpp-driver ... FAILED
    See ...php-driver-master\ext\\build\log\cpp-driver.log for more details
```

If I look in that file then I find the following error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
Update cpp-driver submodule ... The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just clone the https://github.com/datastax/php-driver at my D:somefolder on windows 10 pc. After that it's working fine for me.